# Creating Azure B2B login system with Vue.js frontend & Python Django backend

Tags: django, azure, vue.js, authentication, msal

I'm working on a full stack application using Vue.js for the frontend and Python Django for the backend. Now I want to set up my login system based on Microsoft Entra for my tenant (B2B).

As my website is a SPA, my initial thought was to set it up with MS docs for public client. See also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code). I've got it working.

However, as I have a webapp with backend, [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=windows) would be more suitable and safe (right!?).

I'm trying to implement this logic, but as this logic is rendering the frontend from the python files I'm confused (as i'm rendering and organizing my front-end logic from the Vue.js side). My question is, what would be the best approach for my application, and how to proceed?

I'm aware that my question is broad, but I'm really stuck...

Implemented [this logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code) successfully, but [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=windows) is probably more safe/suitable.